# Rsync bash script and hard linking files

Tags: macos, bash, backup, rsync, hfs

I am creating a bash script to backup my files with rsync.

Backups all come from a single directory. 
I only want new or modified files to be backed up.

Currently, I am telling rsync to backup the dir, and to check the files compared to the last backup.

The way I am doing this is

```
THE_TIME=`date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S"`
rsync -aP --link-dest=/Backup/Current /usr/home/user/backup /Backup/Backup-$THE_TIME
rm -f /Backup/Current
ln -s /Backup/Backup-$THE_TIME /Backup/Current
```

I am pretty sure I have the syntax correct for this. Each backup will check against the "Current" folder, and upload only as necesary. It will then delete the Current folder, and re-create the symlink to the newest backup it just did.

I am getting an error when I run the script:

> ```
> rsync: link "/Backup/Backup-2010-08-04-12:21:15/dgs1200series_manual_310.pdf"
> ```
>
> => /Backup/Current/dgs1200series_manual_310.pdf
>   failed: Operation not supported (45)

The host OS is running HFS filesystem, which supports hard linking. I am trying to figure out if something else is not supporting this, or if I have a problem in my code.

Thanks for any help

Edit:

I am able to create a hard link on my local machine.
I am also able to create a hard link on the remote server (when logged in locally)
I am NOT able to create a hard link on the remote server when mounted via afp. Even if both files exist on the server.

I am guessing this is a limitation of afp.

Comment: I've got the same error, "rsync: link [...] Operation not supported (45)" because the target filesystem (local) don't support hard link (ExFAT)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things from the man page stand out that are worth checking:

> If  file's  aren't linking, double-check their attributes.  Also
>                 check if some attributes are getting forced outside  of  rsync's
>                 control,  such  a  mount  option  that squishes root to a single
>                 user, or mounts a removable drive with generic  ownership  (such
>                 as OS X's “Ignore ownership on this volume” option).

and

> Note that rsync versions prior to 2.6.1 had  a  bug  that  could
>                 prevent  --link-dest  from working properly for a non-super-user
>                 when -o was specified (or implied by -a).  You  can  work-around
>                 this bug by avoiding the -o option when sending to an old rsync.

Do you have the "ignore ownership" option turned on? What version of `rsync` do you have?

Also, have you tried manually creating a similar hardlink using `ln` at the command line?

Comment: rsync  version 2.6.9  protocol version 29
And I have successfully created the exact same link via command line

I will give the other options a shot in a minute here, Thanks a ton.

Comment: @David: Hard links can't be made from one filesystem to another.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case your command line is only an example: Be sure to always specify the link-dest directory with an **absolute** pathname! That’s something which took me quite some time to figure out …

Comment: This is weird. For some reason, specifying target as ./myfile didn't work but /Users/dankle/myfile did work... Anyway, it worked so +1 :)

Comment: @Daniel, it would works with a relative paths, but the trick is that it needs to be relative to the *destination* directory. So in your case, it might be something like "../myfile".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is the same issue, but I know that rsync can't sync a file when the destination is a FAT32 partition and the filename has a ":" (colon) in it. [The source filesystem is ext3, and the destination is FAT32]

Try reconfiguring the `date` command so that it doesn't use a colon and see if that makes a difference.

e.g.

```
THE_TIME=`date "+%Y-%m-%dT%H_%_%S"`
```